# How to exit the following graphical interface in macOS iTerm2?

Tags: vue.js, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

#### I am creating a new Vue.js project(`vue create projectName`).

1. To check whether it could be created correctly, I input the `npm run serve`. Successfully, it works.
2. But I don not know how to stop it and exit the graphical interface.

[image]

Comment: `Ctrl-C` ......

Comment: `command+c` is invalid in macOS

Comment: Ctrl = CONTROL ....

Comment: I am so stupid, it works with the `Control + C`, Thanks.